# variable may not have been initialized error

Tags: java, android

I am using extras to pass a variable between instances, and I initiated the variable but android studio gives me an error saying it may not be initialized...

```
public class TasteNotePage extends ActionbarMenu {

    String beerID = "a";
    Dialog dialog = null;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tastenote_page);
        //get beer data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        beerID = b.getString("id");



        //get beer name, get our review if you have one, get all reviews and set

        //check if user has beer
        String url2 = "myURL";
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);
        String userURLComp = "x=" + userID;
        String beerID = "&z=" + beerID;
```

The error occurs at beerID in the last line of the code above. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `String` before the line

```
  beerID = "&z=" + beerID;
```

The `String` signals the program that you are creating a new variable local to the method, which hides the attribute `beerID` from the class. And obviously, when later in the line you try to use its value, it has not been initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

The last `beerID` on the last line is referring to the local variable `beerID`, rather than the member variable. Either change it to `beerID = "&z=" + beerID;`, if you want to assign to the member variable, or else change it to `String beerID = "&z=" + this.beerID;` if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variable again in `onCreate` instead of using the once declared on the class - in this case it is not initialised:

```
String beerID = "&z=" + beerID;
```

I guess it should be:

```
beerID = "&z=" + beerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized beerID twice. Remove one of the String from the second one if they are supposed to be the same variable.